# Exclude certain Objects from showing up as unused parameters

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I was wondering if it is possible to exclude certain objects by default from showing up as a sonar issue "unused parameter".

I have certain Objects that I sometimes need in a method later on and pass on by default (just one at a time). Without using //NOSONAR or SuppressWarnings which looks ugly (especially since I would need it often in that class), is there a way to disable the "unused parameter" rule for a certain parameter object type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no way to specify a whitelist of types. Why would you need that? Why not specify the parameter only when you actually need it?

Comment: @Tamas It's more of a framework that I'm working on. We have a mechanism in place, that allows users of that framework to extend the framework class and overwrite (or extend) that method functionality. Those projects sometimes need the additional parameter.

Comment: As far as I remember, methods that can be overridden (so `virtual`) are excluded from the check. Similarly overriding methods and interface implementations are also not reported. Could you give an example of your framework mechanism? Is it reflection based? Adding parameters to an analyzer is not straight forward, also this seems like a very specific use case. You could disable the rule for the given files with `SuppressMessageAttribute` if this pattern is specific to only a couple of classes.